# Number of open file in a C++ program

Tags: c++, file, fopen

Is there a simple way to get the number of files opened by a c++ program.

I would like to do it from my code, ideally in C++.

I found [this blog article](http://blog.lobstertechnology.com/2005/08/22/determine-the-number-of-open-files/) which is using a loop through all the available file descriptor and testing the result of `fstat` but I am wondering if there is any simpler way to do that.

#### Edit

It seems that there are no other solution than keeping a count of the files opened. Thanks to everybody for your help.

Kevin

Comment: Yap, keep track of it manually.

Comment: From inside the program or from outside ?

Comment: Took a look at the blog post - yuck. Depending on your system, there may be a way to do it, but the only truly portable solution is to do it yourself as suggested by @H2CO3. What OS(es) are you targetting?

Comment: @H2CO3: thanks for the advise :), I will do in that way if there is no other solution :)

Comment: @MatthieuRouget: from inside the program.

Comment: I feel this is an "XY question". Why do you want to know the number of files open, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I want to track a bug in my application. For some reason, it does not close correctly the files it has opened.

Comment: Are the files `fstream` or `cstdio` type files? I expect they are `FILE *` rather than `fstream`, as `fstream` should close on destruction, so much harder to leak.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: yep they are FILE*. The problem is that I am getting "Too many open files"

Comment: Well, see my answer, you can apply the same method to your fopen calls as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since the files are `FILE *`, we could do something like this:

In a headerfile that gets included everywhere:

```
#define fopen(x, y) debug_fopen(x, y, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define fclose(x)   debug_fclose(x)
```

in "debugfile.cpp" (must obviously NOT use the above `#define`'s)

```
struct FileInfo
{
   FileInfo(const char *nm, const char fl, int ln) :  
      name(nm), file(fl), line(ln) {}

   std::string name;
   const char *file;
   int line;
};

std::map<FILE*, FileInfo> filemap;

FILE *debug_fopen(const char *fname, const char *mode, const char *file, int line)
{
   FILE *f = fopen(fname, mode);
   if (f)
   {
      FileInfo inf(fname, file, line);
      filemap[f] = inf;
   }
}

int debug_fclose(FILE *f)
{
   int res = fclose(f);
   filemap.erase(f);
   return res;
}

// Called at some points. 
void debug_list_openfiles()
{
   for( i : filemap )
   {
       cerr << "File" << (void *) i.first << " opened as " << i.second.name 
            << " at " <<  i.second.file << ":" << i.second.line << endl;
   }
}
```

(I haven't compiled this code, and it's meant to show the concept, it may have minor bugs, but I think the concept would hold - as long as your code, and not some third party library is leaking)

Answer (score 2):

This is a legitimate question: I count open file descriptors in unit tests to verify none has leaked. On Linux systems there's one entry in `/proc/self/fd` for each open file descriptor, so you just have to count them. In c++17 it looks like this:

```cpp
long file_descriptor_count() {
  return std::distance(std::filesystem::directory_iterator("/proc/self/fd"), std::filesystem::iterator{});
}
```

Comment: The advantage of this method is that it gets the OS count, including files opened through  `std::fstream` and other methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are under linux, this information is available under `/proc/you_pid/fd`.

Then use, `lstat` on each file descriptor to keep only regular files.

Answer (score 0):

there is a good practice that the scope of file opened in the smallest possible, open dump all information you want, or buffer into the fd, then close.

so this mean usual case we will have 3 fd the std in/out/err, plus all opened files.

keep track of your open files manually is the best, if you keep files opened.

put a global fdCounter variable, 
increment it after a successful file open, decremented after closing

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however, reading the whole content of the files is definitely not possible in my application, in order to optimise RAM consumption. I have considered having a counter but I was looking for an easier way :).

Comment: read as much as you like from the file then close, then open and seek to the last read position. or don't even close if you are just dealing with only one file until before app termination. how big is the application?

Comment: This is a quiet complex application dealing with dozens of files.

Comment: thats great, the bigger the app, its better having a class wrapper that can keep track of files, or at lease a class for each file, what contain current reading location, and file name. everytime you read or write you open file, access it, then close it before returning from the function call :) so file you are dealing with are closed all time until accessed via read/write

Answer (score 0):

If you encapsulated it properly, it should be simple to add reference counters or logging to it and print them to the console.

One approach to debug it is to override the open calls with your own implementation and from there call the real thing. Then you can also put some logging in, to see if you loose file descriptors. How do you open the files? With `open()` or are you using `fopen()`?

Something like this maybe:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <fcntl.h>

inline int log_open(char *p, int flags, int mode)
{
    int fd = ::open(p, flags, mode);
    std::cout << "OPEN: " << fd << std::endl;
    return fd;
}

inline int log_close(int fd)
{
    int rc = ::close(fd);
    std::cout << "CLOSE: " << fd << std::endl;
    return rc;
}

#define open(p, f, m)    log_open(p, f, m)
#define close(fd)   log_close(fd)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = open("tmp.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);

    std::cout << "FD: " <<  fd << std::endl;

    if(fd != -1)
        close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, by the time you need to count the number of file descriptors, you don't know where they were opened, by what submodule or library. Thus, wrapping open/close is not a viable strategy.  Brute-force counting seems to be the only way.

The domain with the orig blog post no longer resolves in DNS. I copy two proposals from [Find current number of open filehandle ( NOT lsof )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163757/find-current-number-of-open-filehandle-not-lsof)

```
int j, n = 0;

// count open file descriptors
for (j = 0;  j < FDMAX;  ++j)     // FDMAX should be retrieved from process limits,
                                  // but a constant value of >=4K should be
                                  // adequate for most systems
{
    int fd = dup (j);
    if (fd < 0)
        continue;
    ++n;
    close (fd);
}
printf ("%d file descriptors open\n", n);
```

and also this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main (void)
{
   DIR *dp;
   struct dirent *ep;

   dp = opendir ("/proc/MYPID/fd/");
   if (dp != NULL)
   {
       while (ep = readdir (dp))
           puts (ep->d_name);
       (void) closedir (dp);
   }
   else
       perror ("Couldn't open the directory");

   return 0;
}
```